# Create a carousel with Wordpress Elementor for text and image side by side

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am looking for a widget to create a carousel with text next to an image for each slide of the carousel.

As easy as this example:

[image]

This can be premium or free plugin, I already tried lots of them but they all seem to miss this little feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Elementor.
Create several templates that you want to use within Slider.

[image]

Then on the page, you will use the Edit Slides widget
And there you will put the shortcode of the templates in each tab

[image]

And it will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Moshe Dvir's solution worked like a charm. The template is easy to create and the shortcode can be found on the templates overview page (access via WP sidebar, below "Elementor").

However, it seemed like it does not work at first so I almost gave up: Turns out that Elementor's **editor does not support this method visually** so you have to check directly on the preview page or live page. Apparently, Elementor also **doesn't accept any changes to the responsive versions** of templates that are fetched via shortcode so I had to inspect the page, get the respective classes and add custom CSS for mobile.

**This worked for me:**

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {.elementor-2001 .elementor-element.elementor-element-11a281fd {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3em 2em;
}

.elementor-2001 .elementor-element.elementor-element-202c04ca {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
}
```